# Read specific CSV files in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to extract some zip files and after extractions reading only specific CSV files from this folder, there is one pattern but I couldnt place the code. The pattern is Im looking numeric name file, here is my code.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = r'C:\Users\han\Desktop\Selenium'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.zip")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(r'C:\Users\han\Desktop\Selenium')

detail = [f for f in listdir(r'C:\Users\han\Desktop\Selenium\detail') if isfile(join(r'C:\Users\han.37\Desktop\Selenium\detail', f))]
```

After this point, my detail list is like this

```
    ['119218.csv',
     '119218_coaching.csv',
     '119218_coaching_comment.csv',
     '119218_emp_monitor.csv',
     '119218_monitor_work_time.csv',
     '119218_reponse_text.csv',
     '119218_response.csv',
     '119219.csv',
]
```

What I want is that reading only numeric ones which are **119218** and **119219** .csv. and ofc `pd.concat`
because they are same shaped data tables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From your file list, you can just filter out the fileNames which has all charcters as digit except for extension `.csv`, and there are numerous ways to do so, one way is to split each on `.csv` and check if all characters in the first item are digit.

```py
files=['119218.csv',
     '119218_coaching.csv',
     '119218_coaching_comment.csv',
     '119218_emp_monitor.csv',
     '119218_monitor_work_time.csv',
     '119218_reponse_text.csv',
     '119218_response.csv',
     '119219.csv',
]
files = [eachFile for eachFile in files if all(c.isdigit() for c in eachFile.split('.csv')[0])]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
['119218.csv', '119219.csv']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to modify this one line:

```py
detail = [f for f in listdir(r'C:\Users\han\Desktop\Selenium\detail') if re.match(r"[0-9]*\.csv", f) and isfile(join(r'C:\Users\han.37\Desktop\Selenium\detail', f))]
```

Don't forget to `import re`